# Why the numbers of biconnected simple graphs of 4 nodes is three?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

It is stated at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiconnectedGraph.html that the numbers of biconnected simple graphs on n = 4 is 3. And it gives the example graphs: "diamond graph", "square graph", and "tetrahedral graph". And I am wondering, why it doesn't count if I add a cross line on the "diamond graph"? Is it because the result is isomorphic to the "tetrahedral graph"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes same as "tetrahedral graph" if you add a cross line on the "diamond graph".

Please focus on each vertices of "diamond graph" which cross line added and "tetrahedral graph".
All vertices of "diamond graph" which cross line added are connected all vertices except own.
All vertices of "tetrahedral graph" are also.